# How to get the value from a class element?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the selected class text.

I have

```
for (var i=0; i<$('.toys').length; i++){

       if($('.toys')[i].text()=='lego'){
         alert('got it');
         return false;
      }
    }
```

html

```
<div class='toys'> toya  </div>
<div class='toys'> lego  </div>
<div class='toys'> toyb  </div>
<div class='toys'> toyc  </div>
```

I got an error saying the  Object # has no method 'text'

How do I fix this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should cache your results to avoid repeating queries to the DOM.

The problem with your code is that using `[]` returns the raw DOM element (*not a jquery object*), and DOM elements do not have the `.text()` method. You should use [`.eq(i)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) instead of `[i]`.

As others have mentioned, though, a more proper way would be to use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) or alternatively to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter)

```
var wanted = $(".toys").filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === 'lego';
});
if (wanted.length){
  alert('got it'); // or do whatever you want with the wanted element..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) use a jQuery [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) loop to iterate over collections, like this:

```
$(".toys").each(function() {
    if($(this).text() == "lego") {
        alert("got it!");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Little nit-pick- "The [$.each() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object."